# Problem with eval and google closure compiler

Tags: javascript, eval, google-closure-compiler

I'm using google closure to compress my code but I have a problem with the following line of code:

```
        eval('this.find(\''+ element_to_append_the_controller+ '\').'+controller_to_load+'(options_for_controller)');
```

I have to use eval because the method (`controller_to_load`) I have to execute on the element is variable and depend on the params I get.

My Problem is that I have to pass an object to that method, so I'm doing that as an String representation of the variable name(`options_for_controller`), but closure will change that name and won't change the variable name in my eval string.

My solutions would be:

- getting the variable name dynamic as string
- parsing object (with callback functions) to string
- disable compressing for these line of codes

But how can I do one of them or is there another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some programmers use eval because they don't realise instead of writing `eval('a.' + b)` you can write `a[b]`

Try this instead of your eval()

```
this.find(element_to_append_the_controller.toString())[controller_to_load](options_for_controller);
```

Comment: thanks, your right, replaced all evals with this type of dynamic execution, awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.find(element_to_append_the_controller.toString())[controller_to_load](options_for_controller)
```

AKA don't use eval.